# AWS Cognito Hosted UI - Internationalization

Tags: amazon-web-services, user-interface, internationalization, amazon-cognito

Does anybody know if it is possible to replace the texts presented on the AWS Cognito hosted UI login screen? I am involved in a project, where we need the strings in Norwegian.

Maybe this feature should be implemented as part of the hosted UI configuration settings, along with the already existing functionality for uploading your own logo, configuring CSS-values for colors/fonts etc.

Comment: Any news on this topic? When can we expect to see this support?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is not possible at this point. I am on the Cognito team and this is definitely on our roadmap (both Internationalization and better control over the UI customization).

Comment: Thanks for you feedback. Do you have any kinde of timeframe for when internationalization of the UI will be implemented.

Comment: Where do I report bugs in the hosted UI? ....and when will the internationalization option be available?

Comment: Internationalisation is the most missing feature in Cognito currently

Comment: I can't believe it!! I am in Brazil and I need to suppose my users know english to be able to  offer then your custom ui? Jesus!!

Comment: @Ionut - any update on when this would be added? 

Is there a place we can upvote this feature?

Comment: Hello, is there any update?  I need login pages in Chinese and Japanese.

Comment: Seems that I18n, internationalization has been supported in the AWS Amplify/Auth package. The AWS Amplify package also simplifies the integration process. Unfortunately this package still has a lot of bugs when it comes to fully supporting the I18n standard. Several text strings in the GUI-components have not been prepared for I18n.

Comment: Still on roadmap after almost 3 years? :(
I need this service in Italian, cannot find a clean way to translate it (I know there is a dirty way through css)

Comment: how is it going with i18n? this is really a fundamental feature

Comment: June 2021 and still waiting. Here is the AWS Forum ticket (https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=897875). Feel free to add comments to see if we can push this to the top of the AWS priority list.

Comment: we have the same issue, work around maybe create an internal ui for sso or something similar

Comment: I have asked the question on AWS re:Post as they did not transfer the AWS ticket mentioned aboved.
https://repost.aws/questions/QURSGiIGzQQ1iyUWLufsRxuQ/how-to-translate-cognito-hosted-ui-forms

Comment: this is 2022 and the feature is not yet ready. any updates ?

Comment: Please add localization it's very important

Comment: 2023 - any updates on this ?

Comment: Hello 2024! i18n on AWS Cognito Hosted UI does not yet seem to be available. Any news?